# Not able to remove drawable, crashes on VM budget

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I am developing an app that uses a kind of local background. The idea is to make this changable. I manage to change the "background" using this code.

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sharedPreferences.getString("PICTURE", ""));
        Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(bMap);
        bac.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        }
```

The problem is that each time i return to the "background screen" the app crashes because of OutOfMemoryError. Then it shows the new background. I need some sort of code that makes that the app does not crash. I manage to this in a ImageView but not in LinearLayout. For ImageView I use this code:

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sharedPreferences.getString("PICTURE", ""));
    image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

And to avoid it from crashing:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();

unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.iv_pic));
System.gc();

}

private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
    view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
        unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
    ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();

unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.iv_pic));
System.gc();

}
```

How do I do the same for a LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of questions asked on SO about the OOM exception and how to deal with it. Please [search the forum](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20OOM) before posting a question.

Some notes:

1. You can release the memory consumed by a `Bitmap` using the `recycle` method (in your code, you can call `bMap.recycle()`)
2. You can retrieve the reference to your `LinearLayout` using `findViewById` and pass that to the `unbindDrawables` like `unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayoutId));`